# Check backward/forward POJO compatibility using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

We're using Java POJOs as messages that flow through a message broker. They are serialized/deserialized using the Jackson JSON library. Each message (POJO) can have multiple versions:

```
class UserCreatedV1 { private String email; private String fullName; }
class UserCreatedV2 { private String email; private String fullName; private String preferredName; }
```

(getters, constructors, etc are omitted). What is the way to:

- ensure no errors happen during deserialization, even when a client that uses `UserCreatedV1` deserializes a json representation of `UserCreatedV2` (or vice-versa)
- statically check if `UserCreatedV2` is backward/forward compatible with `UserCreatedV1` (no need to enforce this though)

Comment: what is your definition of 'backward/forward compatible'? Does it mean all filled fields in versionX are also present on versionY?

Comment: and what is your definition of 'ensure no errors happen'? Fail on build time? Silently ignore on runtime?

Comment: And "statically check" is not clear either.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof I meant that a change in V2 won't cause runtime errors when being deserialised using the V1 pojo. Eg changing a property from String to a boolean is a breaking change.

Comment: @Olivier Yes, ignoring attributes at runtime would be fine. As long as no situation occurs when they can't be mapped at all (I gave an example above, but trying to deserialise a string into a boolean). As for checking statically - given only the two POJOs above, determine that V2 IS backward-compatible with V1.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your POJO with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` so this way when deserializing into POJO v1 the fields that are exclusive to v2 will be ignored, and when deserialising into v2 from JSON v1 missing properties will be set to null. You can read about ignoring unknown properties here: [Jackson Unmarshalling JSON with Unknown Properties](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-json-unknown-properties)

Comment: That's the easier part. I can also disable it globally on the ObjectMapper using `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`. However, this will only work if there are compatibility rules in the first place - ie the other part of the question.

Comment: First - I am saying the opposite - Do NOT fail if you encounter unknown properties. As to how prevent deserialization failure - it is not so simple. One idea is to deserialize it into a MAP and that have a custom code that converts a map into your pojo in such a way that it can not fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jackson library's polymorphic deserialization feature.

Here is an example of how you can use polymorphic deserialization in Jackson to support multiple versions of the UserCreated message:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "version")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = UserCreatedV1.class, name = "v1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = UserCreatedV2.class, name = "v2")
})
public abstract class UserCreated {
    private String email;
    private String fullName;

    // getters/setters
}
```

Next, define the concrete classes:

```
public class UserCreatedV1 extends UserCreated {
    // no additional fields
}

public class UserCreatedV2 extends UserCreated {
    private String preferredName;

    // getters/setters
}
```

When you deserialize a JSON payload, Jackson will automatically determine the version based on the value of the "version" property, and deserialize the payload into the appropriate class.